# Hibernate ManyToOne with FetchType LAZY causes exception even when lazy attribute is not needed

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I am having this problem where I keep getting an exception when loading an entity with a `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` attribute, even though I'm not using the attribute at all. My classes look like this:

```
@Entity
public class JobOffer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) //Here lies the problem
    private User creator;

    //more attributes and methods omitted for brevity

}

public interface JobOfferListableResponse extends WebResponse {
    static WebResponse of(JobOffer jobOffer) {
        return new JobOfferListableResponse() {
            @Override
            public long getId() {
                return jobOffer.getId();
            }

            @Override
            public String getTitle() {
                return jobOffer.getTitle();
            }

            @Override
            public String getDescription() {
                return jobOffer.getDescription();
            }

            @Override
            public String getCreationDate() {
                return jobOffer.getCreationDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DD_MM_YYYY));
            }

            @Override
            public String getExpirationDate() {
                return jobOffer.getExpirationDate().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DD_MM_YYYY));
            }

            @Override
            public String getEducationLevelRequired() {
                return jobOffer.getEducationLevelRequiredValue();
            }

            @Override
            public OperationResult getOperationResult() {
                return OperationResult.RESOURCE_FOUND;
            }
        };
    }
    // getters
}

public class JobOfferFinderService implements JobOfferFinder {
    private final JobOfferRepository jobOfferRepository;

    public JobOfferFinderService(JobOfferRepository jobOfferRepository) {
        this.jobOfferRepository = jobOfferRepository;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public Page<WebResponse> findAllPaginated(int page, int size) {
        Pageable pageable = new PageRequest(page, size, Sort.Direction.ASC, "creationDate");
        return jobOfferRepository.findAll(pageable)
            .map(JobOfferListableResponse::of);
    }
}
```

When I try to fetch the job offers, I get this exception:

```
2018-06-01 13:44:35.477 ERROR 9145 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.p.p.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory  : HHH000142: Javassist Enhancement failed: com.getajob.domain.user.entity.User

java.lang.InstantiationException: com.getajob.domain.user.entity.User_$$_jvst588_b
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistProxyFactory.getProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:671) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4536) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:359) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:274) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1129) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1022) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:639) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:431) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:154) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:128) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1133) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:992) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2617) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2600) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.readPage(SimpleJpaRepository.java:589) [spring-data-jpa-1.11.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:409) [spring-data-jpa-1.11.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:377) [spring-data-jpa-1.11.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:513) [spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:498) [spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:475) [spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) [spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) [spring-tx-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) [spring-data-jpa-1.11.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) [spring-data-commons-1.13.11.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy152.findAll(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at com.getajob.domain.jobOffer.control.JobOfferFinderService.findAllPaginated(JobOfferFinderService.java:44) [classes/:na]
    at com.getajob.domain.jobOffer.control.JobOfferFinderService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3be7a131.invoke(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) [spring-aop-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at com.getajob.domain.jobOffer.control.JobOfferFinderService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$28af434b.findAllPaginated(<generated>) [classes/:na]
    at com.getajob.web.controller.JobOfferController.listJobOffers(JobOfferController.java:36) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:111) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176) [spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.12.RELEASE.jar:1.5.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:96) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.29.jar:8.5.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.getajob.domain.user.entity.User_$$_jvst588_b.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
    ... 170 common frames omitted
```

I could avoid this by making the `ManyToOne` EAGER or by fetching it in some other way, but as you can see, I don't need the `User` attribute for this query, so I don't want to fetch it. Any suggestions?

I'm on a spring boot 1.5.12 project with spring data jpa 1.11.11 BTW

**UPDATE**

As comments suggested, my `User` entity lacked a default constructor. It had one but it was private, which was preventing Hibernate to create a proxy object. Changing its access to protected solved the problem

Comment: can you past code for your user entity? it looks like it is missing default no arg constructor

Comment: @Michal may be right here, you probably missing no arg constructor and thus Hibernate cannot create needed proxy. Try to add it if that's the case and your problem should be solved.

Comment: You're both right! I do have a default constructor on User, but it was private (since I don't want to allow its use outside of JPA/Hibernate). I changed it to protected and that fixed the issue